# WinEdt 9 vs. MikTeX

Tags: miktex, winedt

How do I let WInEdt 9.0 know if and where is MikTeX installed?

What should be installed first, MikTeX or WnEdt 9.0?

What is the relationship between WinEdt and MikTeX ?

Comment: Unrelated, but you should update to WinEdt 10.3.

Comment: I don't know if the INST hack which prolongs unregistered version period to another 30 days works with 10.3. If not, I may have troubles to get back to 9.0. Is 10.3. substatntially better?

Comment: It mainly seems to be more versatile. There's now a  simpler MiKTeX console and you can install a Contribution Manager from WinEdt.org (requires WinEdt 10). Other than that, a contribution integrating JabRef in the tool bar is also available.

Comment: What is JabRef ?

Comment: It's a bibliography manager, written in Java. You can take a look at its [site](http://www.jabref.org/#downloads) for details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WinEdt is an "IDE" (Editor of .tex files)

MiKTeX is a distribution of the myriad of packages that make for a TeX typesetting system.

WinEdt requires one of the TeX systems such as MiKTeX to already be installed.

Installation sequence is thus either MiKTeX (or TeX Live) first. Note they both often include a basic TeXworks editor.

Then **optionally** an additional PDF viewer of choice. It is not essential as some editors will include their own preview. Avoid acrobat unless it is already installed. I am biased towards SumatraPDF and it is the one recommended for WinEdt.

Test the Tex. (no need for any editor yet.)
At a command line run `pdfLaTeX \documentclass{article}\begin{document}Hello my TeX friend\end{document}` then if all is well simply enter `article.pdf` and the result should appear in the viewer. If these don't function now there will be problems later.

Then finally install WinEdt it will self configure around those already correctly installed items.

Comment: Please see my new question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/497852/several-miktexs-and-winedt).